# Is there a systematic approach to avoid the 3 pitfalls(below) of software solutions?

Tags: projects-and-solutions, requirements

1. Developing software solutions which already exist and are available for re-use (either commercial or open-source). AKA "re-inventing the wheel".
2. Same as above, but your solution being broken. AKA "re-inventing the square wheel".
3. Developing solutions for problems which do not exist.

Again, I'm interested in a more **formal** approach, e.g. [TRIZ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithm_of_Inventive_Problems_Solving)

Answer (score 5):

Doing some research beforehand (1) and investing in solid software architecture (2,3) usually helps :)

When you're planning to develop something you always need to calculate the benefits of doing some and the things like the ROI.

You could read more about this in [Agile Estimating and Planning](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131479415) by Mike Cohn

Answer (score 2):

1. Local Market Research
2. Internet Research
3. Google Metrics (Seeing what the Google Count is)